# How to docker-compose up rails and sidekiq container? rm: can't remove '/graph/tmp/pids/server.pid': & `fetch': Operation not permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am booting up an app that utilizes rails, sidekiq, postgresql, redis. However every time I try to boot the app I get either one of these problems.

`rm: can't remove '/graph/tmp/pids/server.pid': No such file or directory`

or

`/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:37:in fetch': Operation not permitted - bs_fetch:atomic_write_cache_file:chmod (Errno::EPERM)`

When I run the containers again this usually resolves itself but I don't understand why this keeps happening. I've pieced together various tutorials for rails and sidekiq and this is the final `docker-compose.yml` file I came up with.

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.2-alpine3.15
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - graph-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.6-alpine3.10
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        - GITHUB_CREDENTIALS=${GITHUB_CREDENTIALS}
        - BUNDLE_GEMS__GRAPHQL__PRO=${BUNDLE_GEMS__GRAPHQL__PRO}
    command: ./entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /graph
    volumes:
      - ./:/graph
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  sidekiq:
    build:  
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        - GITHUB_CREDENTIALS=${GITHUB_CREDENTIALS}
        - BUNDLE_GEMS__GRAPHQL__PRO=${BUNDLE_GEMS__GRAPHQL__PRO}
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - ./:/graph
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - backend
volumes:
  graph-data:
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -f /graph/tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm /graph/tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

I don't really know what is causing this error but what I can tell from other s.o. questions is that there are some kind of race conditions happening with both my rails and sidekiq containers. What am I doing wrong? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the `volumes:` overwrites the entire container `/graph` directory with a host bind mount, that means the `/graph/tmp/...` directory tree is on your host too, and that's potentially related to some of these issues.  (Are you on a native Linux system with SELinux enabled?)  I'd try deleting the `volumes:` block from the `backend` container, and probably also the `working_dir:` and `command:` that should already be set in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to circumvent this problem.

I added the following to docker-compose.yml:

```
   volumes:
      - ./:/graph
      - /graph/tmp
```